# Libfreetype.6.dylib found, but wrong architecture

Tags: macos, command-line, dylib, dyld

I've been trying to run BLAT, a bioinformatics software on my mac, but all you need to know is that it's an executable that I'm running in terminal. I keep getting this error when I try to run it:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/MyName/./blat
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/homebrew/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetype/2.10.4/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this? For the longest time, I was getting the error that it couldn't find libfreetype.6.dylib, but I finally was able to use install_name_tool to I guess direct it to the right place, and now I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but this might help: What does

```
$ file /Users/MyName/./blat
```

say?  Compare with

```
$ file /opt/homebrew/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
```

If they don't match, that both explains your problem and tells you what you're looking for: either a version of **blat** that matches your freetype library, or a version of **freetype** that matches your installed **blat**.